# Почему не работает height в %?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, css3

Почему не работает стиль `height: 50%` для дочернего элемента ?
И как можно это исправить?

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
}
.child {
  background: white;
  height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leaularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.aker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`height: 50%` Работает, но проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь настроить высоту дочернему элементу, не имея настроенной высоты у родителя (`.parent`). Поэтому по-умолчанию класс `parent` принимает автоматическую высоту. Для работы `height` в % необходимо обозначить height для родительского элемента, например, вот так:

```css
.parent {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
}
.child {
  background: white;
  height: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leaularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.aker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.child {
  height: auto;
}
```

Для тех кого интересует 100% почему не срабатывает.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Думаю ответ вполне развёрнутый. Можно посмотреть просто скопировав код.